# Come posso esprimere "lame excuse" o "cheap excuse" in italiano?

Tags: translation, phrase-request

In inglese, l'espressione ["lame excuse"](https://www.lexico.com/definition/lame) significa una scusa molto poco convincente.

In castigliano e in catalano  esiste un modo di dire colloquiale per esprimere questa stessa idea: "excusa barata" (in senso proprio, l'aggettivo  castigliano "barato" e il catalano "barat" si usano per qualificare qualcosa di basso prezzo, di economico).

Curiosamente, ho trovato questa espressione nella traduzione in catalano di Antoni García Santiago e Albert Folch i Folch del libro [*Niels Bohr's times*](https://books.google.es/books?id=sHAYYakLcTMC&pg=PA181&lpg=PA181&dq=%22excusa+barata%22+aix%C3%B2&source=bl&ots=TWgsFZtceP&sig=ACfU3U2UJmsf_O9LhPwf2oucTiFPryEJbg&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiIha-RyMzoAhWh2eAKHUosCWsQ6AEwA3oECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22excusa%20barata%22%20aix%C3%B2&f=false) di Abraham Pais. Allora mi sono accorta che quello che appare nella [versione originale](https://books.google.es/books?redir_esc=y&hl=it&id=XbUPAQAAMAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=excuse) è "cheap excuse". Quindi, in inglese esiste anche l'espressione "cheap excuse", che immagino abbia una sfumatura di qualcosa più spregevole di "lame excuse".

Come potrei rendere queste espressioni in italiano (preferibilmente in modo idiomatico)?

Comment: Per curiosità, il Ragazzini rende “lame excuse” con “una scusa che non regge”. Forse si può fare di meglio.

Comment: Sarebbe anche interessante vedere come è stato espresso nella traduzione italiana dello stesso libro: _Il danese tranquillo. Niels Bohr, un fisico e il suo tempo, 1885-1962_, trad. di D. Canarutto, Boringhieri, Torino 1993.

Comment: Ugh! Quando comincio a mescolare inglese e italiano... :( Sì, @DaG, questo sarebbe davvero interessante. Curioso questo del "danese tranquillo". Non so se Bohr fosse tanto tranquillo.

Comment: Che ne dite di "scusa insulsa" ? Personalmente, mi piace di più "scusa loffia" :)

Answer (score 4):

A "insulsa" già citata in un commento, aggiungerei debole, patetica, penosa, ridicola, vana, assurda, pietosa, insensata, stupida, povera.

Aggiungo qualche riferimento alla definizione dell'originale inglese:

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/submission/3083/lame+excuse
https://www.powerthesaurus.org/lame_excuse/synonyms

--AGGIUNTA--
"Pallida"

Comment: Grazie, @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica. Sarebbe "pietosa" in questo senso riportato dal [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pietoso), vero? «In usi iperbolici, di cosa mal fatta o mal riuscita, o meschina, miserevole e sim.: *un articolo p.; una interpretazione, una recitazione p.; fare una figura pietosa*».

Comment: *Pietosa* suona come l'alternativa più idiomatica per me, ma ovviamente questo può dipendere da persona a persona

Comment: Curioso, @DenisNardin, perché veramente ho dovuto cercare "pietoso" sul dizionario per tentare di capire perché si potesse usare con questo significato. Cioè, le traduzioni letterali degli altri aggettivi si potrebbero anche usare nelle mie lingue per qualificare "excusa", ma non "piadosa" (cast.) né "pietosa" o "piadosa" (cat.). In particolare, "patética" / "patètica" si sono messi molto alla moda (anche troppo: credo che quasi nessuno si ricordi del senso proprio di questi aggettivi).

Comment: @Charo il messaggio che hai diretto a me non è presente nella mia inbox; è successa la stessa cosa a un messaggio recente da Denis. Mah, il software ha più fantasia degli umani. Comunque la risposta al tuo messaggio è sì.

Answer (score 2):

Un altro aggettivo potrebbe essere *[risibile](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/risibile/)*:

> 2. Che suscita il riso, nel senso di derisione, scherno: risibil gobba (Parini); impotente e sprezzabile e risibil nemico (Alfieri); ma per
>    lo più di discorsi, pensieri, azioni, ecc.: parole, minacce, proposte,
>    credenze r.; scuse, giustificazioni r.; contegno, comportamento
>    risibile.

In questo caso la scusa è talmente ridicola e assurda che causa quasi il riso in chi l’ascolta.